# Intent in android - BlackBerry

Tags: android, android-intent, blackberry

I am trying to figure out what the equivalent of "Android Intent" is in BlackBerry Java. I have read similar questions/answers to this but I have been unable to use them. One suggestion was having a method

```java
public class StatusActivity extends MainScreen {

    String strResult;
    String strsessionFirstName;

    public void setResult(String value) {
        strResult = value;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String value) {
        strsessionFirstName = value;
    }
```

which is called from the main class like

```java
if(strResult.equals("credentialaccepted"))
{
    StatusActivity nextScreen = new StatusActivity();
    nextScreen.setFirstName(strsessionFirstName);
```

But this is not working for me. The other option of using `Hashtable`, I have been unable to comprehend. Can anyone explain with sample code? Thanks.

Comment: What is not working for you? Why don't you use Ani object and pass it to the main screen in the main screens constructor ?

Comment: What is not working is that it is not reading the values. The value remains "null". How should I use an object to pass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you've already looked at our [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11375284/blackberry-how-to-pass-data-like-intent-putextra-in-android)?  If not, please read that first.

### Background

BlackBerry doesn't use `Intent` objects, and there is no direct equivalent.  In Android, `Intent` objects are used for different reasons:

1. to simply start an `Activity`
2. to decouple the caller of the `Activity` from the `Activity` itself
3. to help Android manage the lifecycle (create/suspend/resume/destroy) of `Activity` objects, which it could not do if people just created them directly with `new MyActivity();`

So, the question is, for which of those three reasons (or what other reason) are you asking?  My first guess would be #1 ... you just want to be able to start the activity.

First of all, BlackBerry doesn't have the same concept of an `Activity`.  In Android, you have a **View** layer, which is normally represented by your XML layouts, possibly with some custom Java classes that extend the Android `View` class.

Then, Android has an `Activity` layer, which is similar to the **Controller** in a Model-View-Controller pattern.  The `Activity` shouldn't be too tightly coupled to the UI (the **View**), and ideally, it shouldn't contain the back-end data, which should live in a data **Model** layer.

This can be really nice, because programmers can work on the Model and Controller (`Activity`) code, and graphical UI designers who don't know Java can work on the visual design, entirely in XML (and the Layout Editor tool).

BlackBerry doesn't have anything like Android's **View** layer.  To build a BlackBerry UI, if you're using the native BlackBerry Java platform and tools, you have to do it in Java code.  So, for that reason, I find that fewer BlackBerry projects work hard to separate the **Controller** layer from the **View** layer.  Also, I think Model-View-Controller is more important the bigger a software project gets, and relative to desktop applications, smartphone apps are often smaller.  So, for better or worse, I think that's a reason that MVC isn't built into BlackBerry APIs more directly.

### One Solution

So, as your code snippet implies, a lot of people put the logic that would be in an Android `Activity` subclass, into a `Screen` subclass in BlackBerry.  It more closely couples the controller logic with the UI, but sometimes that's acceptable.

If that's what you're comfortable with, then often you will launch your Screens (*Activities*) with code as simple as this:

```java
StatusActivity nextScreen = new StatusActivity();
nextScreen.setFirstName(strsessionFirstName);
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);
```

The logic that an Android `Activity` would have in the `onCreate()` method, to inspect `Intent` extras, and setup the view, could be in the constructor of `StatusActivity`.  If some of the UI initialization depends on the value of `strsessionFirstName`, then you can setup that UI within the `setFirstName()` method:

StatusActivity.java:

```java
private LabelField _nameLabel;

public void setFirstName(String value) {
   if (_nameLabel == null) {
      _nameLabel = new LabelField(value);
      add(_nameLabel); // add the new field to the screen
   } else {
      _nameLabel.setText(value);
   }
}
```

Or, you could pass the firstName `String` into the `StatusActivity` constructor, and set it up then.

### Another Solution

What [Mister Smith was suggesting in the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11390807/119114) I linked to above, was to create a generic interface for all your BlackBerry "activities", where you set properties with key-value pairs.  So, instead of implementing `setFirstName()`, you would do

StatusActivity.java:

```java
private Hashtable _extras = new Hashtable();
private LabelField _nameLabel;

public void putExtra(String name, Object value) {
    _extras.put(name, value);
}

// NOTE: this method is private now, and can only be called from inside this class!
private void setFirstName(String value) {
   if (_nameLabel == null) {
      _nameLabel = new LabelField(value);
      add(_nameLabel); // add the new field to the screen
   } else {
      _nameLabel.setText(value);
   }
}

// this overrides a base class method, and is called with the screen is displayed
public void onUiEngineAttached(boolean attached) {
    super.onUiEngineAttached(attached);
    if (attached) {
        String firstName = _extras.get("first_name");
        setFirstName(firstName);
    }
}
```

You could then start the `StatusActivity` like this:

```java
StatusActivity nextScreen = new StatusActivity();
nextScreen.putExtra("first_name", strsessionFirstName);
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);
```

Comment: Thank you Nate. Finally got it working. My issue was the values were not being read in "StatusActivity". Finally working now. Thanks again.